# Hashrate of R9 280X is extremely low. Why?

Tags: hashrate

I have an ASUS R9 280X graphics card running with Windows 10, 16 GB of RAM and an Intel i7 6700 processor.

Why is my hashrate at 7.5 Mh/s?

I did expect a hashrate of arround 20 Mh/s. Will the installation of ethOS rise my hashrate? Or should I install another driver?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Have you fixed your problem? I'm also experiencing very los hashrate with a Nvidia GTX 1050Ti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gigabyte r9 280x windforce and it's currently at 12 to 14 Mh/s at stock settings using windows 7 with driver auto installed by the OS.

Yes, it should be at around 20Mh/s but that was for last year. The difficulty has certainly increased since then resulting to a significant drop in hashrate.

You can try ethos but you won't get anywhere near 20Mh/s.

Comment: I didn't think the hashrate was affected by difficulty. Surely the hashrate would stay the same, it's just the hashing would be less successful with a higher difficulty?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, I think you're right -- the size of the DAG (which happens over time) affects the hash rate for some cards. Mining on the Ethereum testnet, Ethereum Classic, or the Ethereum main net shouldn't affect GPU hash rates, even though the difficulty is vastly different (although the epoch that the different chains are on might differ).

Answer (score 0):

download the amd beta block chain driver(just enter that in google you will find it), It fixes the dag slowdown issue, I have not seen a post from someone with a R9 card sharing their increase although the driver lists these cards as supported, and it helps a decent amount with the polaris cards so post your hashrate increase once youve changed drivers !